# How can I fix `flake8 D100 — Missing docstring` error in atom editor

Tags: python, atom-editor, flake8

I installed atom for python programming
and also installed Linter and **flake8** 
packages but everything I write in text editor I get this warning :

> `D100 — Missing docstring in public module`

I already tried

> ```
>  pip uninstall flake8-docstrings
>  pip install Flake8-pep257
> ```

How can I fix this warning ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure linter-flake8 like any Atom package by editing the settings in Atom -> Preferences -> Packages -> linter-flake8.

Use "ignore error codes" for any errors that you don't want to see.

Answer (score 15):

Its nothing but a comment like this on the top of your program. According to Python Documentation it should be there before every function and program. Here is a simple docstring code

"""Return the pathname of the KOS root directory."""

Answer (score 0):

install "linter-ui-default dependencies" from the atom packages store..
It helped me.. for the first time it could not be installed. I restarted Atom and it asked me to install this package. clicking on yes it was installed successfully. And now I am not getting any error.