# How do I disable D100 and or C0111 with ruff?

Tags: python, docstring, ruff

I use sphinx and at the top of my py files I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
my-module
=========
Some notes about my module
"""
```

These warning are incorrect in the this context:

- 1 blank line required between summary line and descriptionFlake8(D205)
- First line should end with a periodFlake8(D400)

I can't put a blank line above ======= because that breaks the headings and I also don't want to put a period after my heading. How can I ignore in just these cases?

This two posts seem relevant:

- [How can I fix `flake8 D100 — Missing docstring` error in atom editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192576/how-can-i-fix-flake8-d100-missing-docstring-error-in-atom-editor)
- [How do I disable "missing docstring" warnings at a file-level in Pylint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877522/how-do-i-disable-missing-docstring-warnings-at-a-file-level-in-pylint)

In my project.toml this did nothing:

```
[tool.ruff.lint]
ignore = ["D100"]
```

I can't even find out how to disable

I also opened a GitHub issue: https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/issues/9583

## Edit

Maybe I'm not understanding how D100 works? It looks like it's been officially implemented as I see a check next to it: https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/issues/970

Shouldn't ignoring D100 prevent docstring linting at the top of the files?

Comment: Your title says D100 and C0111, but the question is about D205 and D400.

Comment: No my question is about how to implement something like missing-module-docstring for ruff. D205 and D400 are the specific docstring warnings, but there is suppose to be a way to differentiate at the file/module level.

Comment: I understand, I thought some rules encapsulated others, but I guess it doesn't work like that.

Comment: The docstring is conceptually wrong because the first line should be a description not an rst heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have paid more attention to my tooltips, the ruff extension gave me a solution. It's a pain to do it in all files, but it's good enough, I guess a multiline string is considered one line because this works:

```
"""
my_module
=========
This is a heading I want sphinx to process
"""  # noqa: D205, D400
```